# Can't open datetime picker in angular app

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-ui

I wanted to use http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ in my angular app.

So in the head tag I included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('datetimepicker.css') }}"/>
```

and

```
<script src="{{ asset('jquery-1.9.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
      $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
</script>
```

I want to apply the datetimepicker like this

```
<input type="text" value="2012-06-15 14:45" readonly class="form_datetime">
```

However the picker is not triggered when I click on the input field and there is absolutely no error in the firebug console.

Where might be the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: Learn how to write an AngularJS directive and why you would need to. If you're loading the inputs in asynchronously or via js, it won't **just** work.